# Python: how to merge two dataframes based on columns condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`

```
df1
     x    y    20   60   80
0   .3   .2     1    0    0
1   .5   .3     0    1    0
2   .5   .1     1    0    1
```

and

```
df2
     20   40   60   80   100
0    0     0    0    0     0
1    0     0    0    0     0
2    0     0    0    0     0
```

I would like to add all the columns of `df2` into `df1` while keeping the values equal to 1 in `df1`. At the I would like the following:

```
df1
     x    y    20    40   60   80   100
0   .3   .2     1     0    0    0    0
1   .5   .3     0     0    1    0    0
2   .5   .1     1     0    0    1    0
```

Comment: ``df1.add(df2, fill_value = 0)`` ? or a bit extra : ``df1.add(df2, fill_value = 0).reindex(columns = df1.columns.union(df2.columns, sort = False))``

Comment: it seems to work :-)